# How can I use an SSL certificate on one domain when content is on another?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have an SSL certificate for **domainb.com** and I'll be hosting an existing user registration page and database on it, but I want people to come from **domaina.com** to remain on their domain page, say **domaina.com/register**.

Will my SSL certificate show for those users visiting in that method? Do I need to purchase an additional SSL for **domaina.com** and will that even work if the content is hosted on another domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is on domaina.com then no, the SSL will not work because it is only valid for domainb.com. In order for SSL to work on domaina.com, it would also need an SSL.

For the second question, yes it would work fine because all content is hosted on a secure URL. (since both would have an SSL)